# Show Excel to Gridview in VB

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net, devexpress

I want to know how to Import from Excel to show on Gridview or VB, but I do not know how to do a previous view, only Exports, but it does not Import.

This is the code I use:

```
sql.Export_Excel(GridControl1, "Test" & TimeOfDay.Second & ".xls")
```

Import or Export:

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server or Dev Express..?

Comment: the sql, I use is for Export to Excel, but I want to Import to show on GridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DevExpress.DataAccess.Excel.ExcelDataSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.DataAccess.Excel.ExcelDataSource..ctor).

Your code should be something like this:

```
Dim excelDS As New ExcelDataSource()
excelDS.Name = "My Excel Data Source" 
excelDS.FileName = "pathtoexcel.xlsx"
Dim worksheet As New ExcelWorksheetSettings("DemoData", "A1:G50")
excelDS.SourceOptions = New ExcelSourceOptions(worksheet)
excelDS.Fill()
gridControl.DataSource = excelDS
```